# Text frame in LaTeX

Tags: text, frame

I want to use text frames like below in LaTeX:

[image: Text Frame]

Is there a way to do so without inserting an image? I don't want it to be exactly like this frame.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe have a look at the [`pgfornament`](https://ctan.org/pkg/pgfornament) package.

Comment: @luki Thank a lot. I've found what i need.

Comment: @Shayan If you found answer, yon can make `self answer` for your question, so that it will help some one who needs help in future...

Comment: @luki Please post your answer so I can mark it as the answer.

Comment: @Shayan Done. I’ll try to add an example later if I find time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such decorations can be drawn using the [`pgfornament`](https://ctan.org/pkg/pgfornament) package.